# There are performance issues combining VueJS and Django?

Tags: django, vue.js

I have decided to use VueJS with Django. Will there any performance issue happen with this? if any, should I use webpack loader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is NO. There are no performance issues using Django and VueJS.

The bottleneck in most of web applications is the database access. Django uses its own ORM which is really easy to work with and very well documented but not famous by its performance.

Given that VueJS is a frontend library, it has no impact in the database access and/or backend stuff, so the combination of Django+Vue will be pretty similar to a 100% Django application.

Having said that, notice that you will probably have to implement a Django backend using a toolkit like [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and many Django features like Forms and Jinja templates will be useless. Implementing all that functionality with a frontend library like Vue, can reduce the requests and data exchange between clients and server, so thus, the performance can improve significantly in applications with small DB access.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Cartucho. I may user Django REST API with VueJS

Comment: You're welcome! Can you please mark the question as resolved?

Comment: I have searched for an option to mark resolved but could not find it. I am new to StackOverflow